# ¿Cómo crear una tabla con html sin usar <table>?

Tags: html5, css3, tablas, html-tabla

*Buenas!* En este código intenté hacer una tabla sin usar la etiqueta table pero quería saber si es considerado responsive hacer tablas con la etiqueta table o si hay alguna otra manera de hacer una tabla con HTML? En la materia que curso en la universidad una profe comentó que ya no es algo que se use actualmente pero en los videos que veo y paginas solo lo explican de esa manera. Intenté hacerlo así pero seguramente no sea lo correcto.

```css
.contenedor {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      border-style: solid;
    }

    img,
    p {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #h2-tabla {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<main>


    <article id="h2-tabla">
      <h2>TITULO DEL CUADRO</h2>
    </article>
    <section class="contenedor">
      <div class="col">
        <p>contenido</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
        <p>10 min</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
      </div>


    </section>

    <section class="contenedor">
      <div class="col">
        <p>contenido</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
        <p>10 min</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contenedor">
      <div class="col">
        <p>contenido</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
        <p>10 min</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
      </div>
    </section>


  </main>
```

Comment: La otra forma es con [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: Digamos que puedes crear algo que se parezca a una tabla sin usar `table`, pero eso no será una tabla propiamente dicha. Sería como decir, *quiero beber agua, sin beber agua*. - Bien, bebo vino, bebo cerveza, que contienen agua. Tampoco puedes, porque no quieres agua en el componente de lo que quieres beber. Si necesitas una tabla, usa una tabla, y si quieres que ésta sea responsiva, hazla responsiva. Si necesitas otra cosa, usa esa otra cosa. Por necesidad se entiende: ¿vas a filtrar datos, o a ordenar datos por sus columnas por ejemplo? ¿acaso hay algo mejor que una tabla para eso?

Comment: quizas tu profesor con 'ya no se usa actualmente' quiso decir que ahora se usan frameworks para facilitar la creación de tablas, pero no veo porque no puedas usar <table> y que se vea bonito y responsivo, si usas bien CSS deberias poder crear una tabla bien vista y que se muestre bien en todos los dispositivos, eso si solo deberias usarlas para mostrar datos estructurados.

Comment: Antes se usaba `table` para maquetar la página web, esa práctica es la que ya no está en uso. Puedes usar `table` y agregarle el diseño adaptativo usando CSS, aquí un ejemplo https://css-tricks.com/making-tables-responsive-with-minimal-css/

Comment: Justo venia a comentar algo como lo que puso @Lobos. Lo más probable es que tu hayas confundido la explicación de la profe. Pero usar tablas es perfectamente útil para todo lo que ya te habían comentado antes.

Answer (score 0):

La gran mayoría de las etiquetas HTML difieren en sus atributos y reglas CSS que tienen predeterminadas. Las `table`, `td`, `tr`, etc caen en este grupo. Es decir si tu modificas estas reglas puedes convertir su funcionamiento en otra cosa, como por ejemplo que un `td` funcione como un `div` o un `span`. Entonces esta sería una manera de hacerlo. Personalmente no me gusta, porque hay que reescribir muchas reglas y es más fácil usar `grid`

Con `grid` tienes al menos 2 posibilidades, la primera es crear una sola grilla que funcione como tabla, y la otra que es la que te recomiendo, es crear una grilla por fila, de esta manera se tiene más control

Pero primero, ¿Por qué `grid` y no `flex`, como lo tienes tu?, porque en flex no tienes control del ancho de las columnas. Tu ejemplo funciona porque tienes exactamente el mismo texto para las cada columna, pero si pones textos diferentes veras como se desplaza. Entonces a ocupar `grid`

```css
.contenedor {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px 40px;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border:solid;
}
.contenedor div{
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:480px){

.contenedor {
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<main>


<article id="h2-tabla">
  <h2>TITULO DEL CUADRO</h2>
</article>

<section class="contenedor">
  <div class="col">
    <p>contenido</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
    <p>10 min</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
  </div>


</section>

<section class="contenedor">
  <div class="col">
    <p>contenido</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
    <p>10 min</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
  </div>
</section>

<section class="contenedor">
  <div class="col">
    <p>contenido</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
    <p>10 min</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
  </div>
</section>


  </main>
```

Como puedes ver, con un simple media query cambiamos la cantidad de columnas y nos queda responsive.

La versatilidad del `grid` es tal, que hay veces que nisiquiera en necesario usar media query, basta con usar funciones como `repeat`, `minmax`, `min`,`max` y `clamp`